# Using a Timeline to display animation when a button is pressed.

Tags: javafx, sprite, timeline

I am making a small game where the user can make a character walk around the screen and make it preform an attack motion. All of the images to create the animation are saved in arrays. For my game loop I am using an AnimationTimer and everything is working the way I want it to as far as the user being able to control the character and the character being abel to move around the screen. However, The problem I am having is that the AnimationTimer runs to fast for when I want to display the character attacking and it runs through the array of attack images so fast that all you are able to see is the ending image. So I tried to set it up so that when the space bar is pressed to attack it would start a Timeline and then the Timeline would through the array of attack images at a slower rate. I want the Timeline to run 15 time(size of the attack array), display all the images in the attack array, then return back to the game. I am not sure if I am using the Timeline correctly because it seems that the Timeline is not consistently running the same number of times every time it is called. So my question is how would I be able to solve my problem of being able to display and array of images at a slower rate but still be able to use my original game loop?
All my arrays are the same size so attackDown.length is the size of all the arrays. My method attack() gets called from my main class every time the space bar is pressed. That is controlled by an AnimationTimer.

```
  public void attack(GraphicsContext gc){
     Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(2500),
            e ->attackDisplay(gc)));
     timeline.setCycleCount(attackDown.length);
     timeline.play();
 }


 private void attackDisplay(GraphicsContext gc){
     System.out.println("in attack" + " a: " + a);
     if(a < (attackDown.length-1))
        a++;
     else
        a = 0;
     if(facing == 'D'){
        gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        gc.drawImage(attackDown[a],xLoc,yLoc);
     }else if(facing == 'U'){
        gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        gc.drawImage(attackUp[a],xLoc,yLoc);
     }else if(facing == 'L'){
        gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        gc.drawImage(attackLeft[a],xLoc,yLoc);
     }else if(facing == 'R'){
        gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        gc.drawImage(attackRight[a],xLoc,yLoc);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hm good question,i will have a look.